# Double printing the endnote using enotez

Tags: enotez

I have an endnote in the caption of a figure environment. When compiled the endnote is printed twice.

However, if b5paper option is  removed, or one or two words are removed from the caption preceding  the endnote command  the  numbering is correct.

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,draft]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[split=chapter,reset=true]{enotez}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{title}
More generally, `it is to this source we must look for the increase of property of every description\endnote{Some text.}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
        \caption{for five British manufacturing sectors, 1730–1820. 1780 = 100.\endnote{Data from R. V. Jackson, ‘Rates of Industrial Growth during the Industrial Revolution,’ EHR 45 (1992), 18.}}
    \end{center}
    \label{figure31}
\end{figure}
    \printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a report on https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/enotez/issues

Comment: I won't promise a solution, though. Captions are moving arguments and as such difficult places for any kinds of notes.

Comment: It's ok. thank you. I'll also report it on bitbucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MANUAL SOLUTION** (see below for automation of this approach)

An ugly workaround...  I use a `\textsuperscript` to set the endnote number inside of the caption, and then I set the `\endnote` in a temporary box outside of the caption.

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,draft]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[split=chapter,reset=true]{enotez}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{title}
More generally, `it is to this source we must look for the increase of property of every description\endnote{Some text.}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
        \caption{for five British manufacturing sectors, 1730–1820. 1780 = 100.%
        \textsuperscript{\the\numexpr\theendnote+1\relax}}
        \setbox0=\hbox{\endnote{Data from R. V. Jackson, ‘Rates of Industrial Growth during the Industrial Revolution,’ EHR 45 (1992), 18.}}
    \end{center}
    \label{figure31}
\end{figure}
    \printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

**AUTOMATIC SOLUTION** (if only one endnote per caption)

Here I introduce `\encaption[<toc-caption-text>]{<caption-text>}{<endnote-text>}` for captions that include exactly one endnote.  Inside the `caption-text`, one should use `\entag` to signify where the endnote tag is to be placed.

This is set up so that the endnote tag does not show up in the list of figures, per the OP's comment to egreg.

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,draft]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[split=chapter,reset=true]{enotez}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand\encaption[3][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\caption{#2}\setbox0=\hbox{\endnote{#3}}\else%
  \caption[#1]{#2}\setbox0=\hbox{\endnote{#3}}\fi
}
\def\entag{\protect\entaghelp}
\def\setentag{\def\entaghelp{\textsuperscript{\the\numexpr\theendnote+1\relax}}}
\let\entaghelp\relax
\apptocmd{\listoffigures}{\setentag}{}{}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{title}
More generally, `it is to this source we must look for the increase of property of every description\endnote{Some text.}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
        \encaption{for five British manufacturing sectors, 1730–1820. 1780 = 100.%
        \entag}{%
        Data from R. V. Jackson, ‘Rates of Industrial Growth during the Industrial Revolution,’ EHR 45 (1992), 18.}
    \label{figure31}
\end{figure}
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I  think at the end if there were no solution I'll use yours.

Comment: @nima See my revision which shows an automatic approach if the caption contains only a single endnote.

Comment: @nima If there is a need for captions with more than a single endnote in them, let me know and I will try to automate that, as well.

Comment: no I don't think there would be any caption with more than one endnote. Thanks for the automation.

Comment: @nima You are welcome.  Remember, if there is no `\listoffigures`, `\setentag` can be invoked directly to activate it.

Comment: @nima The definition `\def\entaghelp{\textsuperscript{\the\numexpr\theendnote+1\relax}}` needs to occur at some point.  It is done with `\setentag`, which is set up to invoke itself at the end of the list of figures.  But if you have no list of figures, `\setentag` will never get invoked automatically.  If you omit the list of figures, you will need instead to invoke `\setentag` manually.

Comment: Aha, I removed ``list of figures'' and the superscript for the endnote get lost, and I just put \setentag instead of \listoffigures and everything got correct. I'll ask further question to this post in chat if there were any. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It is a tough problem; the standard working of `\caption` is to typeset it for getting its size. This already stores the endnote text in memory; *if* the caption is wider than the text width, it is typeset *again* and this stores the endnote once more. This is your case.

A solution is to avoid this double typesetting of the caption text.

You have to use the optional argument anyway, if you compile the list of figures, or the endnote would appear also there.

The package should implement `\endnotemark` and `\endnotetext` for this case. According to the documentation, the author deems them to not be needed: he's wrong. The counter used to store the current endnote number should also be publicly available.

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,draft]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[split=chapter,reset=true]{enotez}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
%%% ugly hack for not typesetting twice the endnote
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \begingroup
  \def\endnote##1{%
    \textsuperscript{\the\numexpr\csname g__enotez_endnote_id_int\endcsname+1}%
  }%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \endgroup
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \endgroup
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil#1: #2\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}

More generally, `it is to this source we must look 
for the increase of property of every description\endnote{Some text.}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption[for five British manufacturing sectors, 1730--1820. 1780 = 100.]%
        {for five British manufacturing sectors, 1730--1820. 1780 = 100.%
         \endnote{Data from R. V. Jackson, ‘Rates of Industrial Growth
         during the Industrial Revolution,’ EHR 45 (1992), 18.}}
\label{figure31}
\end{figure}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

By the way, don't use `center` in a `figure` environment; if you prefer its enlarged spacing, fine, but don't set the label outside the `center` environment: it must be at the same group level as `\caption`.

Comment: No I  don't want it. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I am not sure why, when I compile your code, the problem of duplicate endnotes does not disappear.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes OMG!

Comment: Sorry I'm just ever novice and I really didn't get what you explained. But I actually liked it that there was an explanation for it.